# How to get the object of self children from a parent-child relationship model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am making an application like Twitter's clone with Django and DRF, among which the following models are available.
Reply is a model that defines the parent-child relationship of Post.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    tweet = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def children(self):
        reply_obj = Reply.objects.filter(parent=self)
        children = []
        for obj in reply_obj:
            children.append(obj)
        return children


class Reply(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Post,
        related_name='parent_post',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    child = models.ForeignKey(
        Post,
        related_name='child_post',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I'd like to get a list of Post object that become children of that Post with property `children`.
However, if you write `Post.objects.get (id = 1) .children` in View, for example, you can use`<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager. <Locals> .RelatedManager object at 0x10d0395c0>`
Is returned, and I can not get the expected result.
How can I get good results?

Comment: Can't you do `post = Post.objects.get(id=1)` and then `children = post.child_post_set.all()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any of that code. Just use the reverse relation.

Given an instance of Post, you can do:

```
my_post.parent_post.all()
```